# How to return inside a net request function that already returns something about the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to return the `data` that runs inside `newReq.on('response', (response) => {`,

```
var request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { app, net, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const { session } = require('electron');

function getCode(){
  //GET CODE
  var code;

  var newReq = net.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://url.com/",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': 'lang=en;'
    }
  })
    
  newReq.on('response', (response) => {
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      //process data...
      code = data;
      return data;

  })

  newReq.on('error', (err) => {console.log(err)})
  newReq.end()

  return code; //returns undefined of course, because the function doesn't await for the newReq.on('response') to finish
}
```

yet if i do,  `return newReq.on('response', (response) => {`, it returns bunch of arrays about the request itself, and i can never return the data

`return code` at the bottome returns `undefined` of course, because I try to set it a value inside `newReq.on('response')` but the function doesn't wait for that to end. Also I tried to set `eventEmitter`, same scenario.

How can I return the `data`'s value for `getCode()` ?

Answer (score 2):

For an asynchronous call like the one above, you'd have to move towards using promises. The code above would look something like this:

```
 function getCode(){
    //GET CODE
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var newReq = net.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://url.com/",
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Cookie': 'lang=en;'
            }
          })
            
          newReq.on('response', (response) => {
            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
              //process data...
              resolve(chunk);
          })
        
          newReq.on('error', reject})
          newReq.end()
    });
}
```

The caller for `getCode` would then have to `await` on the promise returned or use a .then something like this:

```
getCode().then((chunk) => {....})
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. if i ```resolve()``` inside ```try catch``` for a  ```new Promise()``` it'd still work fine, yes ? :)